Automatically skip the line number if the line begins with several spaces?
In the following case
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\begin{document}

{\verbatim\linenumbers
A
B
     C
     D
E}

\end{document}

what can be done to have line number skipped in the rest if the line begins with a space, in this case,
1 A

2 B

      C

      D

3 E

How to pattern match to the spaces to toggle linenumber on and off in this way?
